# Change in pH when boiling off acidic water

Tags: physical-chemistry, ph

Assume 1 L of deionized water at pH 2 at ambient pressure open to atmosphere. I boil off 500 mL. I believe the pH will not change because to the same extend as water boils off it will also boil off H+ ions. Correct?

Comment: Deionized water can't have pH 2.

Comment: Its set to 2 using HCl.

Comment: What is the acid?

Comment: The Cl- also get boiled off? I understand vapour droplets are still a macroscopic object where molecules and ions can be dissolved in.

Comment: HCl gas will be lost

Comment: So pH stays or increases even?

Answer (score 3):

$\rm H^+$ ions (as well as any other ions, for that matter) **do not** boil off. Acid does. Depending on the nature of the acid, it might boil off faster or slower than water, and hence your pH might shift up or down.

$\ce{HCl}$, in particular, forms a high-boiling [azeotrope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azeotrope) with water at 22%, so the solution of pH 2 (which is pretty dilute) would form a vapor enriched with water, and the liquid phase would get enriched with acid. So despite the seemingly volatile nature of $\ce{HCl}$, it will mostly stay in the solution and make it progressively **more acidic** as it boils.

Answer (score 0):

With the original question and additional comments provided by you, I find it difficult to answer.  "Deionized water", at ambient temperature, is neutral, i.e. with a pH value of 7.  This is in contradiction with your statement of acidification to pH = 2 by addition of HCl, as in a dilute aqueous solution, the later will dissociate completely into $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ -- but this is no longer "deionized water", rather than hydrochloric acid.

To add to this situation, heating such a solution will not simply boil off water, as HCl forms a negative azeotropic, see for example the phase diagrams depicted [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrochloric_acid).

Thirdly, the original question perhaps accidentally omits to keep an eye on the defintion of the pH value, as

$pH = -\lg{c(\ce{H+})}$

If the [autoprotolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-ionization_of_water) of water -- your solvent of HCl -- is considered simultaneously, described by the equilibrium of

$\ce{H2O <=> H+ + OH-}$

an increase of temperature favours the dissociation to dynamically yield *both* new $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$.  Since the pH value is tied to the concentration of the $\ce{H+}$, a neutral probe (neither acidic, nor basic) of boiling water deviates from a pH = 7.  Even if boiling water still consists mostly of non-dissociated $\ce{H2O}$.

Comment: Agree to your remark on deionized. To me, deionized meaned that ions other than Cl-were removed (so its not just tap water). On the temperature dependence of pH, the second measurement is done after cooling back to room temp.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for acidic water is CO2 , which water can readily absorb from the atmosphere. Boiling the water will drive off the CO2 and make the pH less acidic. The cause of most of "acid rain". 
I once worked at a large R & D facility that had distilled water plumbed through all the buildings : It was consistently pH 3 from CO2.

Answer (score -1):

Chloride is well known (by chemists) as a volatile element. Chloride salts are easily lost upon heating. At STP, HCl is a *gas*. Consider these factors and you should not be surprised to learn that in a solution of H<sub>2</sub>O and HCl, both will be lost upon heating. Since HCl is a strong acid, a pH of 2 indicates that there is 0.01 M/L of HCl present. At 100°C, the solubility of HCl in water is about half what it is at 0°C, but it is still much higher than 0.01 moles/L. I would expect just a little HCl loss of chloride during boiling. Therefore a reasonable first approximation would be to assume no loss of HCl, and hence the concentration will go from 0.01 to ~0.02 moles/L. As a second approximation, you could determine the vapor pressure of HCl at STP and at 100°C, and somehow account for the difference. Since vapor pressure assumes equilibrium, rather than a dynamic process, this would only indicate the approximate magnitude of the loss. In other words, since the distillation process would depend on the heating rates, the surface area of the liquid, the air pressure, the air flow speed and volume, there's no accurate way -other than actual measurement - to calculate the loss. I suspect it would be small, but I'd expect the distilled water to have a pH slightly lower than predicted for pure deionized & distilled water (assuming it's saturated with the other gasses found in the air stream).    The idea that H<sup>+</sup> will vaporize off along with the H<sub>2</sub>O is wrong. You must always assume charge balance. Which means that both the H<sup>+</sup> and the Cl<sup>-</sup> would have to be volatile and exactly as volatile as the water. Like balancing a pencil on its point, that would be possible, but highly unlikely.